# How to make my Flutter app generate numbers only when it is needed?

Tags: events, flutter, dart, state

So the idea of my program is to generate random numbers with operators and then make a non-for-user result of this operation. And it works, but my app refreshes the data **every time I make any action** like opening TextField or submitting the result to compare user input with an actual answer.
I guess the problem is because of bad State managment but I cant figure out how to fix it myself.
(I have my own Mathematics class with functions for program but where is no need to worry about)

The code what`s **required**:

```
class _GameplayPageState extends State<GameplayPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var mathManager = Mathematics();
    var firstNum = mathManager.getNumber();
    var secondNum = mathManager.getNumber();
    var mathOperator = mathManager.getOperator();
    var calResult = mathManager.calculate(firstNum, mathOperator, secondNum);


     Positioned(
                top: 120,
                child: Container(
                  width: screenWidth,
                  height: 230,
                  // decoration: BoxDecoration(color: Colors.orange),
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Container(
                      child: Row(
                        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 10,
                          ),
//                    >>>> LOOK HERE
                          Text(
                            firstNum.toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                fontSize: 100,
                                color: Color(0xff52de97),
                                letterSpacing: 0.5),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            mathOperator,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                              fontSize: 70,
                              color: Color(0xff52de97),
                            ),
                          ),
                          Text(
                            secondNum.toString(),
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                              fontSize: 100,
                              color: Color(0xff52de97),
                              letterSpacing: 0.5,
                            ),
                          ),
                          SizedBox(
                            width: 10,
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
child: TextField(
                          onSubmitted: (String value) async {
                            await showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (BuildContext context) {
                                return AlertDialog(
                                  content: (value == calResult ? Text('Right') : Text('Wrong!')),
                                );
                              });
                          },

                 FlatButton(
                            onPressed: () {
                              setState(() {

                              });
                            },
```

Sorry for bad formatting ;(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure with what you are trying to achieve but here's simple code you can try which don't generate new number after checking if the input correct or not and also has new generate number button

```
import 'dart:math';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Pageone(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class Pageone extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _PageoneState createState() => _PageoneState();
}

class _PageoneState extends State<Pageone> {
  TextEditingController controller = TextEditingController();

  int a = Random().nextInt(10);
  int b = Random().nextInt(10);
  int c;

  String result;

  @override
  void initState() {
    plus();
    super.initState();
  }

  void plus() {
    c = a + b;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
              Text(
                '$a',
                style: TextStyle(
                    fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                    fontSize: 100,
                    color: Color(0xff52de97),
                    letterSpacing: 0.5),
              ),
              Text(
                '$b',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                  fontSize: 100,
                  color: Color(0xff52de97),
                ),
              ),
              Text(
                '$c',
                style: TextStyle(
                  fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                  fontSize: 100,
                  color: Color(0xff52de97),
                  letterSpacing: 0.5,
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                width: 10,
              ),
            ],
          ),
          Form(
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  width: 300,
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: controller,
                    onFieldSubmitted: (String value) {
                      setState(() =>
                          result = int.parse(value) == c ? 'true' : 'false');
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
          Text(
            result == null ? '' : '$result',
            style: TextStyle(
                fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                fontSize: 100,
                color: Color(0xff52de97),
                letterSpacing: 0.5),
          ),
          MaterialButton(
            child: Text('Generate new'),
            onPressed: () {
              setState(() {
                a = Random().nextInt(10);
                b = Random().nextInt(10);
                plus();
              });
            },
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try creating a separate **stateful** widget to contain the part of code where the setstate() is called and convert the original widget to a **stateless** one.

In your code, the GameplayPage widget rebuilds itself whenever any value is updated. This is because the setstate() causes the widget to rebuild. So you should separate the things that don't change and those that change into different widgets.

For example, you can create the FlatButton as a custom widget and sent the necessary details as parameters.

Comment: Thanks for advice! I'm gonna try it but how can I make my widget appear only after I press the FlatButton?

Comment: what you can do is create a variable _show_ and set it to false. inside onPressed of the FlatButton change it to true. And before the TextField add `if (show) TextField(...)`.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

So I solved this problem via making my mathematics object into several functions and then doing the hardest work before `Widget build`. The code:

```
  var b = (Random().nextInt(99) + 1);
  var operate = getOperator();
  var result;
  @override
  void initState(){
    result = calculate(a,operate,b);
    super.initState();
  }
```

Thanks everyone for contributing!

Comment: It's pretty much the same as I did, moving all the variables out of build method (because calling setState() rebuild everything in build method)